# Syntax to update a field in strongloop using angular js client

Tags: angularjs, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using below code to update strongloop model from angularJS client.

```
Customers.update({access_token : localStorage.getItem("accessToken")},{id: localStorage.getItem("userId"), lastlogin : localStorage.getItem("signinTime")
        }, function(success) {
            console.log(success);
            defer.resolve(success);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            defer.reject(error);
        }).$promise;
```

URL is:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/customers/update?access_token=EbgIvaRu0141yXB7QeK7JPqWSFr5dwlQQBWnAxcUnOLBmWhVq8IFmhEuqgxVz2xl&id=55f814c414009bf51bdd7633
```

Here why "update" is appending in url? Please tell me the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I found, why update is appending in url. In lb-services.js, updateAll method appending "update" in the url.

Solution to update strongloop's model properties from angularjs client using restapi is,

```
Customers.prototype$updateAttributes({access_token : localStorage.getItem("accessToken")}, {id : localStorage.getItem("userId"), lastlogin: localStorage.getItem("signinTime")}
            , function(success) {
                defer.resolve(success);
            }, function(error) {
                defer.reject(error);
            }).$promise;
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who may face that problem, You can try **$resource** instance's **$save()** method.

```
// Create or use your current instance
var customer = new Customer({name: 'name'});
customer.$save(null,function(customer){
    defer.resolve(success);
});
```